In InDesign, Print to pdf with Adobe PDF printer, generates low dpi pdf
In so many attempts to print my booklet to pdf with Adobe PDF printer, with almost all presets, I get same low DPI result - I attach a sample project in saved in my InDesign and its printed-to-pdf files as well.
I had to export to JPG a main project because of some transparency flattening problems, then to make a booklet pdf for print provider, I've found that all exported- and then placed 300dpi JPGs exported as low quality raster images - maybe 100 or 72 dpi.
Changed to almost all Adobe PDF printer presets, but still same low quality result.
Don't know where I went wrong.

WOikOdMyJxTzlj5F/view?usp=sharing

Why are you "printing to PDF"? Export to PDF if you are using InDesign. The "Adobe PDF Printer" is like 20+ years old.

to Scott:
I am in need of save my project as booklet - print booklet as I mentioned is where I HAVE to Print as PDF - and it is why I have to use Adobe PDF - Yes it is very old and still while I use 2024 version - it does not support X2001 newer version!!
Don't know if there is any better way of export to pdf booklet - tell me - really appreciate it.
****** *******  >>>> to cybernetic.nomad:
It is not about placed images quality, it is about exported file quality - as you see it in image I sent

@cybernetic.nomad, exactly what I was about to say except you can skip exporting the first PDF and just place the indd file in another indd.

It's a strange print provider that requires you to deliver imposed pages. They should just accept a normal single page document and take care of the rest for you. Find another place, seriously.

needs clarity: Is this "booklet" being self published? Are you sending files to a print provider? Have you checked their specifications/requirements? The "print booklet" command is generally to print on an end-use home printer. It is not something used for a commercial print providers.

I just only can support @Scott's question. Export to PDF, and if you really, really must do additional stuff, do that in Acrobat. Otherwise, also follow the advice of others, get another printing service provider.

Hey guys Wolff, cybernetic.nomad, Scott, Max Wyss, Thanks for every suggestion, @cybernatic.nomad's suggestion for using Distiller was the solution I was looking for, it worked like a charm, really appreciate it people.
Check topic's answer for more.

@cybernatic.nomad - I am asking you to post your suggest as an answer, so I can check it as Solved! Thanks.

@cybernatic.nomad's - also to answer your question - "... why mention them?" the topic was about export issue - my place JPGs are 300dpi images and won't down sampled since they placed - but export was the issue - because those placed hi-res images got destroyed after pdf export. btw as I say- you can see now problem is gone because .ps files exported then converted to pdf by Distiller has no issues. Thanks a lot to remind me of that little software!


Print booklet to Postscript file.

Then use Distiller to convert.ps file to .pdf based on a pdf-x or a high quality preset.


This solution suggested by @cybernetic.nomad
